# ANTLR 4 settings lost on restarting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr4

I am using the latest version of ANTLR 4 plugin on my Eclipse installation that comes with version 4.4 of ANTLR. However, I would like to use the latest version of ANTLR, which is 4.8.

There is an option on the ANTLR-4 preferences where I can choose my preferred version for my project. However, once I restart the options are lost.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Same problem here. You can change the project or global runtime but at next restart, v4.4. is configured again.